# How do I stop expanding the width of the input box after it reaches a certain distance (measured in pixels)?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem with this certain code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function Expand(obj){
      if (!obj.savesize) obj.savesize=obj.size;
      obj.size=Math.max(obj.savesize,obj.value.length);
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form>
       <input  type="text" size="5" style="font-family:Courier;" onkeyup="Expand(this);">
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The thing is that, it's working fine, but the width of the input box keeps on increasing and increasing. I want the expansion to stop after it reaches a certain limit. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.min` like this (Assuming your max size is 30):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Expand(obj) {
      if (!obj.savesize) obj.savesize = obj.size;
      obj.size = Math.min(30, Math.max(obj.savesize, obj.value.length));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" size="5" style="font-family:Courier;" onkeydown="Expand(this);">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyways, I suggest you to style your input with CSS and set the width from there. If you don't know how to do it, this could be a good starting point:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp

Comment: Nope, it's not working. The width still keeps on increasing.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Look at the edited please and try again.